# MySQL - Sum of items issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm developing a web based reporting system as a school project with MySQL and PHP. This is how my database looks like.

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
|               Bill                            |
|-----------------------------------------------|
|   BillID (pk) |   BillDate    |   AccID (fk)  |
|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|   1           |  xxxx-xx-xx   |   1           |   
|   2           |  xxxx-xx-xx   |   2           |       
+---------------+---------------+---------------+


+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|                 BillItem                                      |
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
|BillItemID (pk)|   Quantity    |   BillID (fk) |ProductID (fk) |
|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|   1           |         10    |       1       |       1       |   
|   2           |         10    |       1       |       2       |       
|   3           |         10            2       |       2       |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+

+-----------------------------------------------+
|                    Product                    |
|-----------------------------------------------|
| ProductID(pk) |   ProductName |     Price     |
|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|   1           |   Product1    |   XX          |
|   2           |   Product2    |   XX          |   
|   3           |   Product3    |   XX          |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+


+-------------------------------+
|            Account            |
|-------------------------------|
|   AccID(pk)   |   UserName    |
|---------------|---------------|
|   1           |   AA          |   
|   2           |   BB          |       
+---------------+---------------+
```

User buys products. For each product system generates a bill item. One bill can have many bill items. User can buy same items,different items or combination of both later again. I want to find out how many items users bought from each product during a particular period of time.

Expected:

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
|   ProductName |   UserName    |    Quantity   |
|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|    Product1   |      AA       |      10       |   
|    Product2   |      AA       |      10       |       
|    Product3   |      AA       |       0       |
|    Product1   |      BB       |       0       |   
|    Product2   |      BB       |      10       |       
|    Product3   |      BB       |       0       |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

My attempts so far:

```
SELECT Product.ProductName AS ProductName, 
Account.UserName AS UserName,
SUM( Billitem.Quantity ) AS Quantity
FROM billitem
INNER JOIN Product ON BillItem.ProductID = Product.ProductID
INNER JOIN Bill ON Billitem.BillID = Bill.BillID
INNER JOIN Account ON Bill.AccID = Account.AccID
WHERE Bill.BillDate >=  'xxxx-xx-xx'AND Bill.BillDate <=  'xxxx-xx-xx'
GROUP BY UserName, ProductName
```

Result:

```
|-----------------------------------------------|
|   ProductName |   UserName    |    Quantity   |
|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|    Product1   |      AA       |   10          |   
|    Product2   |      AA       |   10          |       
|    Product2   |      BB       |   10          |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Is there any way to achieve this with mysql query ?

Comment: what is the problem ? What is this Result mean ? does it expected or your result of above query ?

Comment: its the result of my query. I actually want something like the other table

Comment: So what is wrong with ?

Comment: why not try left join from product table?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I already found the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple issues going on to get the results you are looking for.  First, you have no direct relationship between your `Product` and `Account` tables, but you want to display the cartesian product of both.  You can use a `CROSS JOIN` to produce those desired results.

Second, you need to use an `OUTER JOIN` with your `Bill` and `BillItem` tables and move your `WHERE` criteria to the `JOIN`.

```
SELECT 
    ProductAccounts.ProductName AS ProductName, 
    ProductAccounts.UserName AS UserName,
    COALESCE(SUM(Billitem.Quantity),0) AS Quantity
FROM (
         SELECT P.ProductId, P.ProductName, A.AccId, A.UserName
         FROM Product P CROSS JOIN Account A
    ) ProductAccounts
    LEFT JOIN billitem ON BillItem.ProductID = ProductAccounts.ProductID
    LEFT JOIN Bill ON Billitem.BillID = Bill.BillID 
         AND Bill.BillDate >=  'xxxx-xx-xx'
         AND Bill.BillDate <=  'xxxx-xx-xx'
GROUP BY UserName, ProductName
```

Here is a useful article to help understand joins:

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Comment: To explain, when you do an `INNER JOIN` you only get a result when there is a row in both tables (linked by the join criteria, which they both must satisfy). In your case, you want to include a count of things that aren't there, to get the zero counts. So, you need to get data for all products/accounts, even if there is no bill/billitem. That's why you need a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to include the bill/billitem.

Comment: Bravo. This is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you for the quick reply. Really appreciate it.

Comment: but when there will be big data, is it advisable to use CROSS JOIN? will it not take much time?

Comment: Yes it will take time to execute if you have many records in the database. But i see no other option.